# Why isn't Hagrid removed from Hogwarts sooner in Harry's would-be 7th year?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, hagrid

In the 7th book, when Ron is eventually able to tune in to the Potterwatch radio station with the password "Albus", they mention that there was an attempt to arrest Hagrid for hosting an event at Hogwarts in support of Harry. This means that he remained at Hogwarts for a number of months into Harry's would-be 7th year.

**Why was Hagrid allowed to remain at Hogwarts for so long, seeing as he is half giant, associated with the Order of the Phoenix, and a known close friend of Harry's?**

Any of these things alone would be possible reasons for Snape, under Voldemort's orders, to expel him from the school, or otherwise attempt to arrest or even attack him.

My only guess is they had hoped Harry might attempt to return to Hogwarts to visit Hagrid? Is there anything in the book mentioned that might give a solid hint about the reasoning behind this?

Comment: A few of other possible reasons: Snape is a double agent so might not have wanted to. Hagrid is well liked so removing him isn't the best of ideas. Maybe they were waiting for an excuse to do it to prevent uproar.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I can think of a few possible reasons.

1. Voldemort's regime was predicated on projecting a sense of normalcy despite his secretly controlling things behind the scenes. Hagrid's treatment is not that different than the treatment received by the Weasleys, who were allowed to continue to live normal lives while under constant surveillance. It's only once Ron was outed as traveling with Harry that they were forced to flee, despite their obvious sympathies from the start. McGonnagal, another former member of the Order of the Phoenix, is also allowed to continue to teach.
2. This was likely Snape's doing. Elsewhere in *Deathly Hallows* it's mentioned that Snape has placed Hagrid in charge of "punishing" students by making them work in the Forbidden Forest. While certainly frightening, in reality it was far safer and less traumatic than being tortured by the Carrows. Snape faced the difficult task of publicly appearing to support Voldemort's regime while protecting the students and staff, so presumably he came up with a reason to protect Hagrid until the situation became untenable.
3. The Ministry previously attempted to arrest Hagrid in *Order of the Phoenix*. It ended with the Aurors getting their butts kicked and Hagrid running into the forest. His giant blood grants him a degree of immunity to curses and spells that makes him an incredibly dangerous opponent. Why not let sleeping dragons lie?
4. Conversely, a frequent theme of the books is the Death Eaters' arrogance and failure to understand the strength of those who are "beneath" them. In their eyes, Hagrid is an uneducated, feral halfbreed without a wand. They don't even kill Hagrid during the Battle of Hogwarts, only tying him up to mock him.

Comment: I think the Snape explanation only goes so far: since he was playing a loyal Death Eater, there needed to be an explanation for why Snape-as-Death-Eater would keep Hagrid, so Snape could give that reason to the other Death Eaters. So there's still the question of what reason there is for the Death Eaters to keep Hagrid.

Comment: Hagrid also did a *ton* of not-enticing work maintaining the grounds of Hogwarts prior to teaching, and there's no indication that anyone else took up those tasks once he got the new job, too. If he's not a threat, and he's doing all the scutwork, why bother to kick him out?

Comment: @Upper_Case indeed, the other candidate for grounds- and keys-keeper would be Filtch, and I don't imagine he'd be capable of dealing with the forest.

Comment: @OrangeDog indeed, and Mrs. Norris wouldn't last very long out there either.

Comment: @TenthJustice "Why not let sleeping dragons lie?" Well, as the Hogwarts motto tells us: Draco Dormines Nunquam Titilandus (Never Tickle a Sleeping Dragon!)